# Draw partial image or clipping diagonally using Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, core-graphics, ios-simulator

I am looking to draw an image using Core Graphics. However I am able to draw the partial image i.e horizontally & vertically. But instead of it I want to have it in a diagonal Way. For more clarification, please refer to below images:

Real Image: [image]

Required Image Output: [image]

Below is the code using to fill the Layer with Color:

```
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x, r.origin.y );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x , r.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x + (r.size.width ), r.origin.y + (r.size.height));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x , r.origin.y + (r.size.height));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x  , r.origin.y);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, [[color objectAtIndex:0]floatValue]/255.0f, [[color objectAtIndex:1]floatValue]/255.0f, [[color objectAtIndex:2]floatValue]/255.0f, .5);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef,[[color objectAtIndex:0]floatValue]/255.0f, [[color objectAtIndex:1]floatValue]/255.0f, [[color objectAtIndex:2]floatValue]/255.0f, 0.5);
    CGContextFillPath(contextRef);
```

Now, I want to draw an image on this Graphics Layer rather than filling color in it. I didn't get any way to crop this image diagonally since we can only pass parameters like Origin x,y & Size Height, Width.

Comment: You can use CGPath to create diagonal and clip image in the path.

Comment: @Vignesh I am to draw the shape using CGContextRef & also the image. But the question is how to cut that image Diagonally ?

Comment: you have to clip context. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3668156/641062

Comment: use mask image search on google you will find some open source implementation. This might do your work http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/05/mgimageutilities/

Comment: Sorry for the above link this will work for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776747/masking-a-uiimage

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to clip the context to the context's current path. Anything you do after having clipped the context will be visible only in that area:

```
UIImage *img = ...;
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x, r.origin.y );
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x , r.origin.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x + (r.size.width ), r.origin.y + (r.size.height));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x , r.origin.y + (r.size.height));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, r.origin.x  , r.origin.y);

// clip context to current path
CGContextClip(contextRef);

// draw image
[img drawInRect:rect];
```

Did this work?

Comment: let me check out this ... pls

Comment: what is variable r?

Comment: This was taken from the question. I believe r and rect were meant to be the same.